# Orthogonality in space with scalar multiplication

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $H = H_\mathbb{C}$ be a space with scalar multiplication $(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}$. Let $x,y\in H$.

> Show if for every $c\in\mathbb{C}, \|x\|\leq \|x+cy\|$, then $(x,y)=0$

where the norm is defined as $\|x\|^2 := (x,x)\geq 0$.

Can't, for the life of me, figure out how to do this one. Have tried:
$$\|x\|\leq \|x+y\|\quad\mbox{and}\quad \|x\|\leq\| x-y\| $$
yielding $2Re (x,y)\leq (y,y)$ and $-2Re (x,y)\leq (y,y)$

How does one conjure $(x,y) =0$ from the premise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring the inequality and rearranging gives $0\le \left| c\right|^2\left( y,\,y\right) + 2\Re \left( c\left( x,\,y\right)\right)$. If $\left( x,\,y\right) \ne 0$, this general result is contradicted by any sufficient small $c$ for which $c\left( x,\,y\right) <0$.

Comment: Or use directly the minimizer $c=-\frac{\overline{(x,y)}}{(y,y)}$.

Comment: Ahm, yes assuming for a contradiction $(x,y)\neq 0$ is a lot simpler. I have a disease, it's called anti-direct-proof-syndrome :(